# Dynamically populate one select based on another

Tags: views, 7, rules, entities, taxonomy-terms

I'm new to Drupal and well aware this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find a situation similar to mine, or maybe I didn't understand it.

I have three content types:

1. *Team* with fields *Team Name*.
2. *Game* with fields *Team 1* and *Team 2*, an entity reference to the *Team* content.
3. *Vid* content type which has a select box for games (entity reference) which I'm able to populate.

On selection of game, the teams (*Team 1* and *Team 2*) should be populated in the select box of another field say *Pass*.

One game can have two teams, several teams exist and each team can be involved in different games.

I've tried the [hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module, conditional select, entity reference limit option, creating [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and populating the entity reference, and tried [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) as well, but either I couldn't work through it or couldn't find the right setup.

Can someone point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try [conditional_fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields)

[Update multiple fields with ajax callback in form](https://www.drupal.org/node/1408994)